# Add a new column between the first and second columns with values that are numbers from 1 to 5, repeated as needed to reach total line number

Tags: awk

I have a txt file with 2 columns, and would want to add a new column between the two that has values ranging from 1 to 5, and repeated as many times as needed to have the same rows as the other columns. I'm trying to use AWK but I'm open to other suggestions

Example Input

```
A 100
A 200
A 300
A 400
A 500
B 1000
B 2000
B 3000
B 4000
B 5000
```

Example output

```
A 1 100
A 2 200
A 3 300
A 4 400
A 5 500
B 1 1000
B 2 2000
B 3 3000
B 4 4000
B 5 5000
```

Right now I'm trying

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) $2 =++i OFS $2}1' $my_data
```

But clearly is not working.

Comment: What would be output if input file has last row as `C 750` ?

Comment: This needs some clarification: `and repeated as many times as needed to have the same rows as the other columns`

Comment: The way I'll generate these files the number of rows will always be multiples of 5. So, if there is a C, it would be five times, and the second column value is irrelevant. Summarising, in case there's C it would be:
```
C 1 750
C 2 1000
C 3 1200
C 4 1500
C 5 1200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With modulo-operator `%`:

```
awk '{print $1, (NR-1)%5+1, $2}' file
```

Output:

```
A 1 100
A 2 200
A 3 300
A 4 400
A 5 500
B 1 1000
B 2 2000
B 3 3000
B 4 4000
B 5 5000
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 3):

A simpler `awk`:

```sh
awk '{print $1, ++cnt[$1], $2}' file

A 1 100
A 2 200
A 3 300
A 4 400
A 5 500
B 1 1000
B 2 2000
B 3 3000
B 4 4000
B 5 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1,a[$1]+=1,$2}' file
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29731214)

Comment: @SuhaibJanjua: It _does_ offer an answer. [Please review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).